# UBUNTU 18.04 - Python2/3 Seems Broken - Unsure Where to Start

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

awhile back before I discovered docker, I was installing multiple python versions here and there to install various apps. Now, I seems to be getting errors often when I attempt running .py scripts. I looked through the list of my /usr/bin and there were a bunch of python on the list that seems to have broken symlinks, but I just don't know where to start (Still a ubuntu noob, but slowly getting a hang of things). Here's my usr/bin results:

```
dre@dreplexlinux:~/PlexAniSync-master$ find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 | grep python | xargs ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1056 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      29 Mar 26  2018 /usr/bin/dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2336 Feb 21  2018 /usr/bin/dh_python3-ply
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3624880 Jul  1 08:56 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jul  1 08:56 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Aug  1  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5477720 Oct 12 12:14 /usr/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4530520 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4530520 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4852896 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4852896 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5183008 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 21  2020 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2971 Jul  1 08:56 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3283 Jun 29 04:45 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3055 Dec  9  2021 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
```

Any advise how to clean this? I feel like I just want to delete everything and start from zero, but not sure where to start....

I have tried reinstalling python again, but didn't seem to get me anywhere.

EDIT1

Ok I think the error is more related to installing some of the package requirements for the script. One of the package I'm suspposed to install is pyreadline. However, when I run:

pip install pyreadline

I got the following:

```html
Keyring is skipped due to an exception: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyreadline
  Using cached pyreadline-2.1.zip (109 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
          from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
          __import__(extant)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
          collections.MutableMapping.register(ParseResults)
      AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Is pyreadline package no longer working?

Comment: None of those symlinks look broken.  That all looks fine.  Why don't you tell us what errors you're getting?  The problems are not here.

Comment: ok, I guess now I'm more confused. I am using plexanisync script to sync plex with anilist. I haven't changed anything on this folder. It used to work before, but now I'm getting the following

dre@dreplexlinux:~/PlexAniSync-master$ python PlexAniSync.py
  File "PlexAniSync.py", line 45
    def read_settings(settings_file) -> configparser.ConfigParser:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

| I thought it was python issue because that was what I have been tweaking around as of late.

Comment: Your `python` link is linked to `python2.7`, and Python 2 does not support the type hints.  Try `python3 PlexAniSync.py`.